# For symmetric $A$, show that $\lVert A \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Let $A$ be a symmetric, real matrix. Show that the following inequality holds true:
$$
\lVert A \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_\infty
$$
where:
$$\lVert A\rVert_2 = \sqrt{\rho(A^tA)}$$
$$\lVert A\rVert_\infty = \max_i\sum_{j = 1}^n \lvert a_{ij} \rvert$$

I personally was stuck at this proof, since I am unsure what to make of the 2-Norm and its definition. My try so far is to try to simplify it:
$$\lVert A \rVert_2 = \sqrt{\rho(A^tA)} = \sqrt{\rho(A\cdot A)} = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^2)} = \lvert\lambda_{\max}(A)\rvert$$
but I am stuck there.

Comment: Of course, the last term should be $|\lambda_{\text{max}}(A)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said: if $A$ is symmetric, then $\|A\|_2 = \rho(A)$. On the other hand, for any (sub-multiplicative) matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$, we have $\rho(A) \leq \|A\|$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I already got that far :) My problem is that I cant relate the eigenvalue to the infinity norm

Comment: Sorry about that!  I guess I wasn't reading carefully; see my latest edit.

Comment: No need to be sorry! I appreciate the help! Regarding your edit: Is that a common theorem? I have never seen that before

Comment: @Katharina Yes it is.  The proof in your case is easy enough: if $\lambda,x$ is an eigen-pair, then
$$
\|Ax\|_{\infty} = \|\lambda x\|_{\infty} \leq |\lambda| \cdot \|x\|_{\infty}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you're looking for a reference for this fact, see section 5.6 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*